# Get access to attributes of selected features stored in AGOL hosted feature layer from within Web AppBuilder

Tags: arcgis-online, geoprocessing-service, arcgis-web-appbuilder

When you are passing one or more selected features into a geoprocessing widget via the ellipsis (...) in Web AppBuilder, what input parameter type do you use so that you can get access to the attributes of the selected feature(s)?

I have an AGOL hosted feature layer inside my Web Appbuilder (Developer 2.4) app that contains the attributes I'd like to work with.  I would like to assign an attribute to a variable so that I can perform some action on it from within the geoprocessing service.  I understand you can use the select widget to select one or more features and then pass those selected features as input to a geoprocessing service via the geoprocessing widget.

Comment: Can you expand on "drill down"? You're right. You can setup the widget to pass a selected set of features in a feature layer and pass that to a GP service. I'm not sure what you're asking in regards to the initial selection.

Comment: @KHibma Maybe if I wrote the question like this:  "When you are passing one or more selected features into a geoprocessing widget via the ellipsis (...) in Web AppBuilder, what input parameter type do you use in the geoprocessing service so that you can get access to the attributes of the selected feature(s)?"

Comment: it has to be a GPFeatureRecordSet, meaning when you published the service you started with either a featureset or a featureclass. And inside the service editor you had selected "user defined value" as the mode.